# Win32 - Change background color under ENTIRE 'Static' control area?

Tags: winapi, colors, background, edit

VS2019 c++
This is how I'm declaring a 'Static' label in my humble Win32 application:

```
hLabel = CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"My Application Text", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD |  ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 20, 50, 700, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Each line of text uses about 25 pixel worth vertically. So I effectively have room for two lines worth of text in this control since it is declared as 50 pixels high.

I would like to override the default colors used to paint the control, so I experiment with this code:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
    HDC hEdit = (HDC)wParam;

    SetTextColor(hEdit, RGB(0, 255, 0));
    SetBkColor(hEdit, RGB(0, 0, 255));

    return 0;
}
```

This works "great" except it does not paint the entire area of the control?
[image]

As you can see above, the Text color is applied to the characters and the 'Background' color is applied not to the entire area of the control, enclosed by the WS_BORDER, but only to the extent of the characters. I start by filling the control with 100 characters. That's why you only see "one" line of text. My question is "how should I go about filling the entire are of the control"? Which is declared as having an area of 700 pixel wide by 50 pixel high.

I confess I searched around quite a bit but I feel I'm going in circle.

Comment: [WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic): *"Return value: If an application processes this message, the return value is a handle to a brush that the system uses to paint the background of the static control."* Your code is returning zero.

Comment: @IInspectable Truth is, the code snippets I found had a return value like "(INT_PTR)GetStockObject(COLOR_WINDOWFRAME) or (LRESULT)GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW). One comment I found said "Do not return a brush created by CreateSolidBrush(...) because you'll get a memory leak".

Comment: Nothing wrong with creating and returning a brush. You just have to manage your resources properly, i.e. create the solid brush only once, and destroy it when it's no longer used. The parent window's `WM_DESTROY` message handler would be a great time to destroy the brush.

Comment: @IInspectable One thing I noticed is that, even if I "return 0", the colors specified are still "applied"? The only "problem" is that the specified backColor is not applied throughout the surface covered by the control. Thank your for taking the time to look at the code and comment!

Comment: You are changing the environment, by setting the text and background color on a [device context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts). Those changes apply to future text rendering calls through that DC. It doesn't change the areas of a control that aren't part of the text rendering, though.

Comment: I took a look at creating and destroying HBRUSH objects and all I could find was something along this line: HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(33, 33, 33)), you see? This is *only* creating a Brush for ONE color? I remember some code who, while analyzing it, led me to believe that the affected color would be the backColor? That it would "retained"? Something to the effect of a "bkgrnd" which I tried but was not recognized by the compiler. It's hard to figure things out, analytically, when the full documentation can't be found.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah! It "does not change the areas of a control that aren't part of the text rendering"! Ah! Now this is really helpful. Didn't come across this  information before.

Comment: Which begs the question "Is it possible to change the color of the Edit control area"? To your knowledge? If I might ask?

Comment: Yes, of course. You just need to handle [WM_CTLCOLOREDIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcoloredit) (and `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` for disabled edit controls), [SetBkMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setbkmode) to `TRANSPARENT`, and return the desired brush handle.

Comment: @IInspectable It works!!!!! I wish I could show the new code in my post but I can't find an "Edit" button?

Comment: The [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67392025/edit) link is right below the question. Although, if your update would ultimately answer the question, you should submit an answer instead.

Comment: @IInspectable But it's not "my" answer? Does it matter? As long as I give credit to the person who helped?

Comment: It's not just possible, it's [explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own question. Attribution isn't require either. If anyone cares enough about history, they can look up the comments. I doubt anyone does, though. People come here to find answers to their problems, and keeping the signal-to-noise ratio high is more important than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "42" -- kidding!

This is how I changed my code :

```
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:   
{
    HDC hEdit = (HDC)wParam;

    SetTextColor(hEdit, RGB(0, 0, 255));    
    SetBkColor(hEdit, RGB(255, 255, 0));
    SetBkMode(hEdit, TRANSPARENT);

    BackEDIT = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 0));

    return (INT_PTR)BackEDIT;
}
```

And then I added :

```
    case WM_DESTROY:        
    DeleteObject(BackEDIT);
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
```

So, adding a BRUSH and deleting the BRUSH. Works perfect!